# Application of Lindeberg-Feller Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to prove that for independent variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ $$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k}{\sqrt{\mathbb V\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k\right)}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mathcal N(0,1),$$
where $\mathbb P(X_n = n) = \mathbb P(X_n = -n) = \frac{1}{2}$. I cant use the normal CLT because the $X_n$ are not identically distributed. I have to use the Lindeberg-Feller Theorem. I know that $\mathbb E(X_n) = 0$ and that $\mathbb V(X_n) = n^2$ and that therefore $$\mathbb V\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k\right) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mathbb V(X_k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$
I know that I need to find $X_{n,k}$ with
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k_n}\mathbb E(X_{n,k}^2)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k_n}\mathbb E(X_{n,k}^2 \mathbf 1_{\{|X_{n,k}|>\varepsilon\}})\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$
for all $\varepsilon >0$. How can I find such $X_{n,k}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are the $X_n$'s independent ?

Comment: @Surb yes they are. Forgot to mention it.

Comment: @YuvalPeres I forgot the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ tank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sigma_n^2:={\mathbb V\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k\right)}=n^3/(3+o(1))$
and define $Y_{n,k}:=X_k/\sigma_n$ for $k \le n$.
Then
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb E(Y_{n,k}^2)=1$.

Moreover, for all $\varepsilon >0$,
if $n$ is large enough, then $|Y_{n,k}|\le n/\sigma_n <\varepsilon$ for all $k \le n$, so $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb E(Y_{n,k}^2 \mathbf 1_{\{|Y_{n,k}|>\varepsilon\}})=0$.

Thus the conditions of the Lindeberg-Feller Theorem are met.

Comment: Thank you! But why does ${\mathbb V\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k\right)}=n^3/(6+o(1))$ hold true? I do understand that ${\mathbb V\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k\right)} \in O(n^3)$.

Comment: There was a typo, now corrected, the correct asymptotic is $n^3/(3+o(1))$. This follows, e.g., from the exact formula given in the original question, $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$.